# How do I compile usbmuxd and make a .dll file?

Tags: usb, compiling

I have usbmuxd and need to compile it to .dll file. within the src folder of usbmuxd i have .h and .o files. Is there anyone who knows how to compile this to .dll? thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can compile Linux source code to a dll file. In Linux we have something called Shared Object, with he extension .so, equivalent to a .dll. You must compile first and then get whatever comes from the compilation.

Comment: DLLs are for Windows. If you really want to build a Windows DLL on Linux, you *could* do it by cross-compiling. But if you just want to build a shared library, then you'll need to build a .so, as @Eduardo says.

Comment: Eduardo, I have a libusbmuxd.so file, so since you say it is equivalent to a .dll file, would it be possible to convert the file to .dll?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. By the way, cross compiling wouldn't work too. Cross compiling compiles for other architectures, not other systems.